# Ruby Equivalent Syntax

Tags: ruby

I see a below syntax in one of the ruby files written by an user. Can someone help me in understanding what the below code means?

```
if fieldWidth==nil
  fW = regStr.length
else
  fW = fieldWidth
  regStr.rjust(fW,'0')   # Left pad with 0s if fW > regStr.length
end

if fW >= fWOld: fWMax = fW end
fWOld = fW
regStrIx = 0
```

Comment: I tried to run it and it didn't work. Are you sure that is the whole line? Maybe you have an indentation problem. Could you give us more code lines?

Comment: I too could not run it.. But this is something the user claims to run on rails. Let me give few more lines of code. `      if fieldWidth==nil
        fW = regStr.length
      else
        fW = fieldWidth
        regStr.rjust(fW,'0')   # Left pad with 0s if fW > regStr.length
      end

      if fW >= fWOld: fWMax = fW end
      fWOld = fW
      regStrIx = 0`

Comment: @dev-cc. Edited with few more lines of code. Does that help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of the *if* conditional, a footnote in The Ruby Programming Language on page 119 : "Ruby 1.8 also allows a colon, but this syntax is no longer legal in 1.9."
A newline or semicolon or the keyword `then` is correct.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thought it was a typo and the OP actually meant  a semicolon.

Comment: Can you let me know the ruby equivalent in Ruby 1.9 and above please.. I am new to the language and have something to migrate from ruby 1.8 to the latest one

Comment: Ok got it... Thanks!! ```if fW >= fWOld then fWMax = fW end```

Comment: How about `fWMax = fW if fW >= fWOld`? Saves you 9 characters...

Comment: @steenslag : Interesting. I wonder whether someone is actually **using** the `then`. I have never seen it in actual code.